# How do you add values(parameters) from controls on different pages to a method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I have a method that is being used to save certains values from controls to a database. Some of the controls are on different pages within the application. The controls(textboxes) are already filled out before the application loads, so I need to have a way to access this data before I actually access the page. I know how to add data from controls from pages that I have already accessed, but what about controls that I havent accessed yet, if this makes sence.

Answer (score 2):

You can't access controls on a page that isn't loaded.

Assuming that all of the data on the pages is related, what you need to do is create a class to hold the values that you collect from various pages, then store the values from each page into the class.

You can then create an instance of this class on the first page in your sequence and store it in the sessionstate for the current user so that it is available to the subsequent pages.